# Trying to make an app which that will display my location in app with marker

Tags: android, android-studio, maps

I am new in android and created a predefined Map project in android studio.
This is my code..

```
      public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;    
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera    
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.getMyLocation();
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));    
    }
}
```

I want that instead of sydney my current location to be displayed with that red marker.
Please be bit easy as i am completely new.
Thanks

Comment: refer comment of this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37251771/getting-current-location-in-android-api-level-23/37251806#37251806

Comment: read this tutorial from [google](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/location/index.html)

Comment: this may guide you a bit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36696024/google-maps-v2-getting-lat-long-value-using-gps?noredirect=1#comment60982808_36696024

Answer (score 0):

> try below code and refer https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intro

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;

    Location location= mMap.getMyLocation();
    LatLng myPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myPosition).title("My Position"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myPosition));

}
```